# Oracle APEX - validation returns a wrong value

Tags: oracle-apex

I created a validation for checking the current password. This is the PL/SQL code:
[image]

When I enter the correct password, it gives me an error message like this:
[image]

I wanted to check what is the value of old_pwd, so I changed the validation type to Function Body (returning Error Text) and then changed the code like this:
[image]

Then, somehow, the value of old_pwd becomes 'ABC', which I entered in the New Password field.
[image]

I have no idea why this happens. Can anyone help me?

[EDIT]

It might not be related, but I have a process after submitting it. It is like this:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the "Submit" process from After Submit to Processes.
server side condition-> when button pressed "submit" button.

Reason being-
[image]

Comment: Wow thank you, it's working now. Could you tell me why I should not put it in After Submit?

Comment: Updated the comment with the reason as well.